# SQLite use UITextfield to select column header

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

This section of code works great. However, there is the opportunity to pick total of 3 of five search choices. With this in mind, I would like to use `UITextField`s for the WHERE. For example, replace "Chain = ?" replaced with "search.text = ?". I am familiar with "WHERE Chain=\"%@\"",_somthing.text" but can't work out how to replace the hard code column header with a `UITextField`.

Can any body please help?

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT FullName FROM storeDetails WHERE (Chain = ? AND Format = ? AND RegionCode = ?)"];

const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(detailspapav2, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [_choiceText1.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Bind 1 failed");
    }
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [_choiceText2.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Bind 2 failed");
    }
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [_choiceText3.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Bind 3 failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have to use C API of SQLite ? why are not using https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb ?

Comment: Will this library give me the options I am looking for, is there any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the column name to be dynamic, change your `querySQL` line to something line:

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT FullName FROM storeDetails WHERE (%@ = ? AND Format = ? AND RegionCode = ?)", search.text];
```

However, this is dangerous. If `search.text` contains a value that doesn't exactly match the name of a column in your `FullName` table, the query will fail.

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you for imparting your knowledge & the search options are from a picker list, so I won't have a problem with no match